# append letter to a string in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a vector:

```
 c("BAAAVAST", "BAACEZ", "BAAGECBA", "LOL")
```

And I would like to remove "BAA" from the words that contain it. And to those words I would like to append ".PR".

Desired outcome:

```
 c("AVAST.PR", "CEZ.PR", "GECBA.PR", "LOL")
```

Any ideas? Ideally using `stringr`. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Does your string always _start_  with "BAA" or do you want to remove "BAA" inside a string? What should happen to "CEZBAAAVAST"?

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
library(stringr)

# optimized thanks to Anoushiravan
str_replace(c("BAAAVAST", "BAACEZ", "BAAGECBA", "LOL"), "BAA(\\w*)", "\\1.PR")
#> [1] "AVAST.PR" "CEZ.PR"   "GECBA.PR" "LOL"
```

- use `\\w*` if you want to match word characters only or `.*` if there are no limitations to the characters.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following solution:

```
gsub("BAA(.*)", "\\1\\.PR", vec)

[1] "AVAST.PR" "CEZ.PR"   "GECBA.PR" "LOL"
```

Comment: Totally right, my first capturing group doesn't make any sense. :D

Comment: You are the master here Martin, I am learning from you and everyone else :) You ever noticed that `regex` cheat sheet is so helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is verbose than the other answers.  It finds strings with `'BAA'` and appends `'PR.'` to it.

```
inds <- grepl('BAA', vec, fixed = TRUE)
vec[inds] <- paste(sub('BAA', '', vec[inds]), 'PR', sep = '.')
vec
#[1] "AVAST.PR" "CEZ.PR"   "GECBA.PR" "LOL"
```